# selecting some rows from Truth Table

Tags: python, logic, enumerate, generate, truthtable

I am using Truths class to generate a truth table :
https://github.com/tr3buchet/truths

However I could not enumerate all rows or extract rows with correct evaluation of expression? Is there a way to do that ?

I received this error :
AttributeError: 'Truths' object has no attribute 'rows'
thanks in advance

I can only get the table printed but I could not change it ?

how can I extracted specific rows from table ?

Answer (score 0):

A `Truths` object stores almost exclusively the information that is provided during initialization. That is: the `base` items, the `phrases` (optional) and the `ints` (also optional).
The only other things are:

- a regex method (which is probably not what you are looking for) and
- a list of `base_conditions`, which stores the part of the table with the `base` columns

The latter one can be accessed like this:

```py
t = Truths(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['(a and b)', 'a and b or c'])  # example
t.base_conditions # == [(False, False, False), (False, False, True), ... (True, True, True)]
```

The rest of the table is generated on the fly when the table is printed.

If you have not done it already, have a look at the [code](https://github.com/tr3buchet/truths/blob/master/truths/truths.py) in the git repository.